# Can I force Doctrine ORM to split up a complicated query?

Tags: php, cakephp, doctrine

I'm making a query with Doctrine that contains lots of joins. Some are hasOne relationships, and some are hasMany.

I think CakePHP makes separate queries for each hasMany relationship, but Doctrine seems to make one huge query. Both can hydrate the data and return a nice array into your php script, but they seem to make different sets of queries to do so. With Doctrine, as soon as your query contains several hasMany joins, performance can become pretty terrible.

With CakePHP, the default is to split the query, but I can force it to join (http://book.cakephp.org/view/872/Joining-tables). Is there a way to do the reverse in Doctrine: to force it to split the hasMany joins into different queries? I've tried the docs and API but not found anything yet.

Comment: What happens if you hydrate it as an object? Shouldn't Doctrine's lazy loading come into play then?

Comment: is your problem not poor indexes on the table(s) you are querying? if i was you i would start by running DESCRIBE on the queries and find out if there is any indexes even being used.

Comment: @dogmatic69, I think you mean EXPLAIN instead of DESCRIBE?

Answer (score 3):

Wrong solution: querying with many joins at once should always be faster than using fragmented queries in multiple SQL statements, provided that your query is correct.

If your query is terribly slow as soon as you add n:n or 1:n joins, in Doctrine, there are several causes for it.

One of the most frequent mistakes in queries with multiple joins, is the use of the LEFT JOIN + WHERE construction where you could use INNER JOIN with ON. Consider this DQL example:

```
SELECT a.*, c.*
  FROM Article a
  LEFT JOIN a.Buyer b
  LEFT JOIN b.Creditcard c
  LEFT JOIN c.digitalinfo d
  WHERE b.id = 2 AND d.info LIKE 'TEST%'
```

This is a very slow query if all tables have 10000 records. It will first join the entire table b with table a, resulting in 10000 ^ 2 rows, whereas in your WHERE clause you throw away pretty much 99,9% of them all.

```
SELECT a.*, c.*
  FROM Article a
  INNER JOIN a.Buyer b WITH b.id=2
  LEFT JOIN b.Creditcard c
  INNER JOIN c.Digitalinfo d WITH d.info LIKE 'TEST%'
```

Here, the INNER JOIN a.Buyer b does not end up with 100 000 000 rows, but since it uses an extended ON clause (Doctrine calles this WITH), it will only leave a small set. Therefore the other two joins will go lightning fast compared to what they performed like in the other statement.

Also, make sure you ALWAYS have indices

- On columns that you search on. (If you search on full name, as in FirstName+' '+LastName, create an index on that sequence!)
- On columns that you do specific joins on
- On foreign keys and the fields they have the reference set to.

If you want to know what your database is doing behind the scenes, you could for example in MySQL type `EXPLAIN` followed by your query, and it tells you exactly why it is taking so long.

Comment: Thanks, I am using LEFT JOIN + WHERE so this will definitely help. There is a second aspect to the poor performance, though, which I didn't explain before. When the data is returned from a single query with lots of hasMany joins, there is a lot of duplication in the data. (i.e. a lot of rows are *almost* identical). The PHP script – Doctrine in this case –  is using lots of memory to hydrate all this duplicated data; I was hoping to split up the queries to reduce the duplication and reduce the amount of memory too.

Comment: A few notes on that. As far as I know, the time Doctrine Hydration takes should be neglectable compared to MySQL's efforts to actually perform the query. Did you profile your application? Doctrine's hydration is a process that should not take much longer than processing a large resultset in any other way. What hydration mode are you using? (try HYDRATE_ARRAY, is a lot faster than doctrine objects.) You can also use the ORM stuff it comes with (i.e. find one item, and then navigate to its relatives, like `$creditcards = Doctrine::getTable('Article')->findOneById($id)->Buyer->Creditcard`

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine lets you join more than one table, traversing more than one oneToMany relationship. That results in a query with an exponential (on number of table joined) number of records.
The hydration process than refines the result set and make a tree from your bidimensional result set (table).
That's reasonable for small result set and few table joined.

If you have relevant number of table and records, you must do separate queries.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem too. I had a query that took 0.0060 seconds to execute in it's raw form but for which the array hydration process took 8 seconds. The query was returning 2180 rows due to the multiple left joins (this was a single entity with all it's relations).

Following @Elvis's solution I dropped the hydration time to 0.3 seconds. What i did was simply split the query in two separate queries, ending up with the first one having 60 records and the other 30 records.